# Why do some variables have values out of bound after solving in CPLEX?

Tags: cplex

I am currently using CPLEX Python API to solve an LP problem. I restricted my variables to be between 0 and a. However, after solving, some variables have values which are negative or > a. What could be the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the solution status after the call to 'solve'? What is the value of [solution.get_status](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.SolutionInterface-class.html#get_status) or 'solution.get_status_string'?

Comment: Hi, the output is "infeasible". Does it mean there is some degree of relaxation involved in these variables to produce the solution?

Comment: It means that CPLEX determined that there is no feasible solution to your problem. You can read more about this [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/cont_optim/simplex/24_soln_quality.html).

Comment: You might try using the [conflict refiner](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.ConflictInterface-class.html#refine) (see also [diagnosing infeasibility by refining conflicts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/infeas_unbd/conflict_refiner/01_ref_confl_title_synopsis.html)).